# how to properly allocate memory in C++ in low memory conditions

Tags: c++, exception, memory, allocation

I have seen resources show two ways of allocating memory while ensuring that there was enough memory to complete the operation.

1) wrap the 'new' operation in a try/catch since it'll return std::bad_alloc (?)

```
try { ptr = new unsigned char[num_bytes]; } catch(...) {}
```

2) check the assigned pointer for null after the 'new' operation.

```
ptr = new unsigned char[num_bytes]; if(ptr == NULL) { ... }
```

Which one is right?  Do they both work?  Do I need to maybe do both 1 and 2?

Thanks,

jbu

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you are using the standard implementatin of `new` which throws exception, then  first one is correct.

You can also use the second one if you use `nothrow` as:

```
ptr = new (nothrow) unsigned char[num_bytes]; 
if(ptr == NULL) { ... }
```

Comment: oooh this is maybe what i should do instead, to reduce the amount of code I'll need to change.

Comment: @jbu: also note that some code is compiled with exceptions off. This is non-standard, and in this case you'll need to read your compiler doc, but chances are that then `new` will return 0 if it fails.

Answer (score 6):

a not successful allocation [using `new`] throws `std::bad_aloc`, so the 1st is correct.

the 2nd is used for c code, when using `malloc` [since there are no exceptions in C, NULL was used to indicate the allocation failed].

when using `new`, the if statement will never yield true, since if the allocation failed - an exception will be thrown, and the if statement will not be reached. and of course when allocation is successful, the if statement will yield false.

Comment: Good advice in general, but many embedded c++ platforms don't support exceptions, and those are the ones where low memory is actually more of a concern.

Comment: "but many embedded c++ platforms don't support exceptions": then they are not supporting C++, but rather a C++-like language. Exceptions are are part os standard C++.

Answer (score 0):

```
try { ptr = new unsigned car[num_bytes]; } 
catch(std::bad_alloc& e) { cerr << "error: " << e.what() << endl; }
```

The second idiom is more appropriate for `malloc`